# JAVA Data Encoding Validation

Tags: java, character-encoding

I need to validate fields that is received from another system. Every field is different encoded. I will know what field use what encoding types. Below is the encoding types that must be used to validate the different fields.

ASCII_STRING_ENCODER - For this I used :

`CharsetEncoder asciiEncoder = Charset.forName("US-ASCII").newEncoder()`

If it is successful I know it is a ASCII String.

Is there any JAVA libraries that I can use to validate a string for the below encoding types?

```
BCD_STRING_ENCODER

EBCDIC_STRING_ENCODER

LITERAL_STRING_ENCODER

ASCII_HEX_BINARY_ENCODER

BCD_BINARY_ENCODER

EBCDIC_HEX_BINARY_ENCODER

LITERAL_BINARY_ENCODER

NO_ENCODER
```

Thanks.

Comment: ASCII and EBCDIC are character sets, LITERAL is a miracle to me, the rest is binary, BCD is every byte's hex digit interpreted as digit.base 10, HEX is clear too.

Comment: did you know you **could** encode a data field (values `0x65 0x66`) with nearly any of these encoders?